# Right click in Windows terminal inserts clipboard contents instead of opening context menu

Tags: windows-10, context-menu, windows-terminal

In my Windows 10 system, right clicking into any console window (cmd, Powershell, Ubuntu on WSL) inserts the clipboard contents instead of opening a context menu.

Is there a setting to change this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is controlled by the "Quck Edit Mode" setting.  If you get used to it, you will never go back to that menu.

Open the system menu for the window and select "Properties"
[image]

Play with "Quick Edit Mode" and "Insert Mode"
[image]

Quick Edit Mode being unchecked will bring your menu back.

Comment: Indeed, now that I know how to use it, I think I'll keep it :) For posterity: QuickEdit mode means you can always highlight text in the console (which you otherwise enable using "Mark"), *Enter* copies highlighted text, and right click pastes.